# Sed to change specific file content permanently

Tags: linux, sed

I am trying to make use of `sed` to make a small change in the below `myfileforsed.txt`

```
sameer:test:1234:foo/faa
saurabh:test:2313:foo/faa
john:test:2314:foo/faa
admin:add:4527:foo/faa
jane:test:2131:foo/faa
```

My requirement:
I want to change `admin:add:4527:foo/faa` into `admin:add:4527:foo/free`

However I am not able to do it with :

```
cat myfileforsed.txt | grep -w admin | sed -i 's/faa/free/'
sed: no input files
```

It is because I am not giving input of file in last.

Can someone suggest me what can be done to achieve this as a single line with sed?

Instead of sed, do you have any other suggestions too as I am new to this world of linux ?

Comment: `cat file | grep something | sed -i 's/this/that/'` will never ever work. `sed` has no file -- only input from stdin.

Answer (score 3):

Given:

```
cat fileforsed.txt
sameer:test:1234:foo/faa
saurabh:test:2313:foo/faa
john:test:2314:foo/faa
admin:add:4527:foo/faa
jane:test:2131:foo/faa
```

You can use `sed` and sed alone to do:

```
sed -E 's/^(admin.*)faa$/\1free/' fileforsed.txt
sameer:test:1234:foo/faa
saurabh:test:2313:foo/faa
john:test:2314:foo/faa
admin:add:4527:foo/free
jane:test:2131:foo/faa
```

Once you have that working for `stdin` THEN add the `-i` flag.

```
sed -i'.bak' -E 's/^(admin.*)faa$/\1free/' fileforsed.txt

head fileforsed*
==> fileforsed.txt <==
sameer:test:1234:foo/faa
saurabh:test:2313:foo/faa
john:test:2314:foo/faa
admin:add:4527:foo/free
jane:test:2131:foo/faa

==> fileforsed.txt.bak <==
sameer:test:1234:foo/faa
saurabh:test:2313:foo/faa
john:test:2314:foo/faa
admin:add:4527:foo/faa
jane:test:2131:foo/faa
```

If you want to use *variables* in the sed script you can do this:

```
admin_var="admin"
replacement="free"

sed -i'.bak' -E 's/^('"$admin_var"'.*)faa$/\1'"$replacement/" fileforsed.txt
```

Or:

```
sed -i'.bak' -E "s/^(${admin_var}.*)faa$/\1${replacement}/" fileforsed.txt
```

(Note the quoting for both those.)

Note:

```
cat file | grep something | sed -i 's/this/that/'
```

will never work since sed is only taking `stdin` input from `grep` and there is no file to change. You can only output from sed to `stdin` and redirect that output to a file. However -- this is not the way to get a line in any case. sed can both read a file and match a line in that file so both `cat` and `grep` are redundant.

Comment: Actually my main concern is to not provide the grep argument inside sed. I will be making use of this inside a script where I will have a variable value of  "admin" and I think passing variable value in sed inside a shell script will be difficult.

Comment: See edit. Is that what you mean by *variable value of "admin"*?

Answer (score 1):

Simple `sed` scripts follow the pattern "filter operation arguments". If you want to substitute text in all lines matching a pattern, use the following sed script: `/\word\b/s/foo/bar/`. The `-i` flag tells flag to edit the file in-place, but for this you need to pass a file path to sed and not feed text through stdin.

```
sed -i '/\badmin\b/s/faa/free/' myfileforsed.txt
```

If you still want/need to combine sed with other programs, write the output to a temporary file and then copy its content over the original file:

```
grep -w 'admin' myfileforsed.txt | sed 's/faa/free/' > tmp.txt && cat tmp.txt > myfileforsed.txt
```